# How to replace a character by regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

How to replace a letter 'b' to 'c' after a duplicate letter 'a' base on 2 times?
for example  :

```
ab => ab
aab => aac
aaab => aaab
aaaab => aaaac
aaaabaaabaab => aaacaabaac
```

Comment: The last example doesn't match in the number of characters (?)

Comment: @SebastiánPalma: I think it's a typo on OP's behalf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check groups of `aa` followed by `b` and then replace captured groups accordingly.

**Regex:** `(?<!a)((?:a{2})+)b`

**Explanation:**

`(?<!a)` checks for presence of an odd numbered `a`. If present whole match fails.

`((?:a{2})+)b` captures an even number of `a` followed by `b`. Outer group is captured and numbered as `\1`.

**Replacement:** `\1c` i.e first captured group followed by `c`.

**Test String:**

```
ab
aab
aaab
aaaab
aaaabaaabaab
```

**After replacement:**

```
ab
aac
aaab
aaaac
aaaacaaabaac
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxVxs0/1/)**