# regex string and substring

Tags: python, regex, substr

I have a character string `'aabaacaba'`. Starting from left, I am trying to get substrings of all sizes >=2, which appear later in the string. For instance, `aa` appears again in the string and so is the case with `ab`.

I wrote following regex code:

```
re.findall(r'([a-z]{2,})(?:[a-z]*)(?:\1)', 'aabaacaba')
```

and I get ['aa'] as answer. Regular expression misses ab pattern. I think this is because of overlapping characters. Please suggest a solution, so that the expression could be fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Does this have to be done with regex?

Comment: @Chris Not necessarily. But it would be great if it could be done with regex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which does not consume matched string:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?=([a-z]{2,})(?=.*\1))', 'aabaacaba')
['aa', 'aba', 'ba']
```

NOTE: `aba` matched instead of `ab`. (trying to match as long as possible)

Comment: Can `[a-z]` be replaced with `\w` as `(?=(\w{2,})(?=.*\1))` (?)

Comment: @SebastiánPalma, Yes it is. But it will also match digits, `_`. I'm not sure whether it's what OP wants or not; so I left it as is (as OP wrote). Maybe `.` is more appropriate if OP wants any character.

Comment: You're totally right, I think he needs just a-z characters, it's similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954326/how-to-replace-a-character-by-regex-in-ruby) question.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma, I couldn't use look-behind assertion, because Python `re` allow only fixed-length look-behind assertion.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. Didn't know that there is no restriction on look-behind assertion.

Comment: @Sumit, You're welcome. BTW, you mean `s/no restriction/a restriction/`, right?

Comment: Sorry I meant that there is no restriction on look ahead assertion. Also, could you please explain why there is a ?= in both the brackets? I would have just done in the second bracket.

Comment: @Sumit, Without the first look-ahead assertion, first matched part will be consumed; overlapped matches(`aba` in this case) will be excluded in the result.

Comment: @falsetru Thank you. Got it.

Comment: @falsetru great answer. I couldn't think about 1st look-ahead assertion. Learnt something new today :)